# How the transformation is possible?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects, transform

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
string[] strings = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six",
                     "seven","eight", "nine" };

 var textNums =
                from n in numbers
                select strings[n];

   Console.WriteLine("Number strings:");

   foreach (var s in textNums)
   {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
   }
```

1) What is the mechanism that transform an "integer" to representing the integer in "word" ?

2) Transformation like such kind is only possible with int to string? or can we do fun with
   this transformation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. It's just array access - it's using the element from "numbers" as the index into the "strings" array.
2. Only integers will work for arrays, but you could equally have a `Dictionary<string, string>` or whatever to do arbitrary mapping. In this case you can think of a string array as being like a `Dictionary<int, string>`. You could rewrite it that way too:

   ```
   int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
   var words = new Dictionary<int, string>
   {
       { 0, "zero" },
       { 1, "one" },
       { 2, "two" },
       { 3, "three" },
       { 4, "four" },
       { 5, "five" },
       { 6, "six" },
       { 7, "seven" },
       { 8, "eight" },
       { 9, "nine" }
   };
   var textNums = from n in numbers
                  select words[n];
   ```

   Console.WriteLine("Number strings:");

   foreach (var s in textNums)
      {
                   Console.WriteLine(s);
      }

That's still using integers - but you can do the same thing with dictionaries where the keys are other types.

Comment: I was expecting your answer for one of my previous questions (Question Title : Linq- Running Total and Sub Total ).If time permits kindly help me in that too.

Comment: Jon, I don't think this is the best solution. Ophs what have I said!?!

Comment: @Tony: It's an explanation of how he could go from the integer version to a non-integer version. It will work for arbitrary types which work as keys in a dictionary - whereas enums won't.

Comment: @linqfying: The answer on that question is already perfectly good. I can't see what more I'd add to it.

Comment: Jon Do you mean answer to the  previous question ?

Comment: I mean the answer to "Linq- Running Total and Sub Total".

Answer (score 5):

No. The string representations are just in the correct order that's all. There is no magic here.

Look at the string array

```
strings[0] = "zero";
strings[1] = "one";
strings[2] = "two";
.
.
```

the fact that its ordered correctly is why the mapping works.

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel bad about my stupidity.I did not go through the example properly.

Answer (score 2):

When you say strings[n] you are accessing the nth value of the array, and the array is ordered like:

strings[0] = "zero";
strings[1] = "one";
...
strings[4] = "four";

So, no magic here, just an ordered array :P

Comment: Sorry ! I did not go through it properly.Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
public enum MyNumberType { 
        Zero = 0, One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
        }
```

You could do what you want with it in the following ways:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum MyNumberType { Zero = 0, One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten }

        private static int GetIntValue(MyNumberType theType) { return (int) theType; }
        private static String GetStringValue(MyNumberType theType) { return Enum.GetName(typeof (MyNumberType),theType); }
        private static MyNumberType GetEnumValue (int theInt) {
            return (MyNumberType) Enum.Parse( typeof(MyNumberType), theInt.ToString() ); }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "{0} {1} {2}", 
                GetIntValue(MyNumberType.Five), 
                GetStringValue( MyNumberType.Three),
                GetEnumValue(7)
                );
            for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", GetEnumValue(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Producing the following output:

```
5 Three Seven
Zero
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
Seven
Eight
Nine
Ten
```

This could be extended for larger numbers and numbers not in a continuous range like so:

```
public enum MyNumberType { 
        ten= 10, Fifty=50, Hundred=100, Thousand=1000
        }
```

Enums can be used with other types as well not just int types so this is very flexible.

Comment: This solution has the disadvantage that you are treating your code as both code and as text.  The fact that an enum named "Three" can be turned into a string is useful in many places, but I feel like it's rather awkward to actually treat the name as a string in user output.

Comment: Additionally it won't work for non-integer types (e.g. strings, floats, Guids), and isn't easily internationalised (unlike a dictionary where you can just have different dictionaries for different languages).

Comment: he doesn't actually say he wants it to cook toast or indeed work internationally.... although he might..... he doesn't like toast I love toast.